# Avoiding busy loop with boost::asio::io_service run

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, busy-loop

I am implementing some asio operations using boost,
I've encountered an interface problem, whom which I am not receiving 'handlers' in initialization, but right after,

This forces me to write a 'busy' loop, what I'd like to do is have the io_service run even without having at least 1 handler, is it possible? what is the way to handle this? do a wait on handlers on the service?
this is my code..

```
    /** : */
    void                Run             () { while(true) {m_srv.run(); Sleep(1);} } // once 1 handler is inside service, thread will not be in busy loop
private: // members:

    io_service  m_srv;
```

Any suggestions? thanks

This is the code problem: (m_drv is a task that operates boost::thread(io_service::run..))

```
class App : public Base::Application
{
public:
    /** : */
    App(char* name, char* id) : Application(name, id), m_drv("NetTask"), m_worker("Worker"), m_acceptor(m_worker, Drv(), &OnAccept, 4567)
    {
        m_acceptor.Accept(Drv());
    }

    /** : */
    inline DriverImp& Drv() { return static_cast<DriverImp&>(m_drv.Imp());}

    /** : */
    inline Reactor& Worker() { return m_worker; }
public: 
    APTR(Socket) m_sock;
private: // members:
    Driver      m_drv;
    Reactor     m_worker;
    Acceptor    m_acceptor;
};
```

Comment: You have a slight problem with your loop: The documentation for [`run`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) states that if `run` returns you have to call [`reset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) before calling `run` again.

Comment: I don't want to ever leave run :), handlers are supposed to exist after start.. but ok, I will look it up, still what is the way to avoid the busy loop?

Comment: It was a couple of years ago since I last used Boost ASIO, and I don't have my source available right now, but as I remember I just put the `io_service.run()` call in its own thread, and didn't have a loop. I *think* it was done before any async calls were made, and it worked fine anyway.

Comment: not according to the boost documentation.. they say you must call run after at least 1 handler is inside the service

Comment: Also, since the run will exit after it's out of work, I don't need to call reset..?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible for `io_service.run()` to block without at least one handler running. However you could simply add a handler for a timer with an extremely long duration to ensure that run does not return...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [io_service::work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html):

```
boost::asio::io_service        service;
boost::asio::io_service::work  work( service );
```

**Note**: in destructor the `work` object notifies the `service` that the work is complete and `io_service::run()` may return.

Comment: I don't see how it helps, worker says it will finish when there are no more handlers, I don't want it to ever finish

Comment: @Alon, sorry, didn't get you. Is the problem solved?

Comment: nope, the worker still exits since it has no work, so I would still have to do while(true)

Comment: It means you're using io_service::work incorrectly. Show us the code.

Comment: In general I am creating the service and then appending work to it, and not vice versa...what is the way to make the service keep checking for work without doing a busy loop?

Comment: Again, it doesn't work that means you're doing it incorrectly. Show me the code or I'll not be able to help. And _forget_ about that loop.

Comment: Ive posted it. what piece are you missing?

Comment: I do not see you use `io_service::work` anywhere in your code. But it is exactly what you need. As long as the `work` object remains alive, any subsequent calls to `io_service.run()` will not return. So you create the `io_service`, then create the `work(io_service)` and then you can call `io_service.run()` whenever you want and be sure that it does not return until you destroy the `work` object (and then finishes all ahndlers).

Comment: thanks DeVadder, @IvanGrynko, thanks for the answer, please revise a 3rd line to call io_service.run() for future users :)